# Arraylist of indices to be removed from another arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing a programming project and part of it requires me to remove some objects from an arraylist of objects. My idea is to go through that arraylist(lets call it main_list) and see which ones need to be removed, and save those indices in another arraylist of integers (lets call it temp), and after everything is done I will go do something like:

```
for (int i=0;i<temp.size();i++){
    main_list.remove(temp.get(i));
}
```

But after I made this, I realized the elements in the arraylist's position is changed after something has been removed.
I made temp by traversing the main_list from index 0 to main_list.size(), so I was thinking maybe I could do something like

```
for (int i=0;i<temp.size();i++){
    main_list.remove(temp.get(i)-i);
}
```

the idea being the offset in the main list at that time would be the same position the element is at in temp.

So I'm just wondering if this logic is correct at all? would this work in offsetting the removal index change in main_list? 
If not, how would I do something like this?

edit: I know it may be better to just do the removal as soon as they are found in the search but in my program, I have many other methods besides remove that require a search on the entire arraylist so I can't really do that

Comment: If you "really" want to do this in a two step process, then traverse the list from the bottom up (`for (int i=temp.size() - 1;i >= 0;i--){` this way, removing an object won't then change all the other indices of the objects are you are trying to remove (assuming that the indices list is order of cause) - a simpler solution might be just to call [`ArrayList#removeAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) passing in a `List` of the objects you want to remove in the first place

Comment: It would be so much easier to build a new a new list with the items you want to keep, but I don't understand why so many people prefer to find hackish ways for removing from the list instead.

Comment: Another simple (but not the best) way could be replace the contents of the indices for deletion with some sort of marker, eg NULL, and then have a second pass where you remove all NULL entries.

Comment: @Tom If only the API was designed with a concept a non-mutable AND mutable `List` - it would be easier to constrain people to what actions were appropriate/expected :(

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I didn't even think of traversing bottom up, the removeAll is interesting too!

Comment: Building a new list is likely to be *more* efficient than most ways of removing elements unless you do something analogous to [erase-remove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to avoid shifting the tail of the list repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply add the valid items to a new `List` and discard the old list.

Comment: Easiest option to get right, and linear time, unlike solutions based on `remove`-ing repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea works, since the list of indices is sorted.  It’s a bit faster, though, to sort them in *descending* order and use the indices as is.  (The speedup comes from shifting fewer elements past the removals.)